Atomic off-resonance absorption in a full quantum theory
When studying atomic absorption in time-dependent theory, we learn (see, for example, Griffiths, 1Ed, pg. 307), that the probability of absorption is given by,
$P_{a\rightarrow b}(t) \propto \frac{\sin^{2}{[(\omega - \omega_{0})t/2]}}{(\omega-\omega_{0})^2}$,
where $\omega$ is the frequency of the external field of radiation and $\omega_{0}$ the frequency associated with the transition between levels $a$ and $b$. This equation clearly allows for off-resonance $(\omega \neq \omega_{0})$ absorption, which in a semiclassical theory, such as the one Griffiths is describing here, presents no conceptual difficulty to understand: the quantized atom absorbs $E = \hbar\omega_{0}$ energy from the classical, continuous field.
My question, however, concerns how can we justify off-resonance absorption in a complete quantum theory. How can an atom absorb the quantized energy $E = \hbar\omega$ of a localized photon and transition to an excited state when $\omega \neq \omega_{0}$? How can the transition occur if the atom received the incorrect amount of energy? I already saw justifications based on the finite lifetimes (and hence, by the uncertainty principle) broadened energy levels, and even in the context of collisions and Doppler effect, but I don't think they answer this question. In the context of what Griffiths is discussing, we have transitions between stationary states $(\Delta t = \infty)$, with no atomic motion or other parameters taken into consideration.
